# laravel 5.6 - connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I test an `laravel 5.6` app running on `localhost:8000`.
I have a separated `vue` project (not the one in laravel but external stand alone vue project) running on `localhost:8080`.

I want `external vue` to call a route from `web.php` in laravel:

```
Route::get('/stores/{store}', 'StoresController@show');
```

My code in `external vue`:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/stores/68')///<-- I do have a record of 68 in database.
.then((response) => {
    console.log(self.postdata);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And I get error:

> GET http://localhost:8000/stores/68 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I tried with IP address too:

```
axios.get('http://192.168.0.142:8000/stores/68')
```

And still get error:

> GET http://192.168.0.142:8000/stores/68 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

After much reading, I suspect is because of the `csrf-token` don't exist in `external vue`.

How can I resolve this?

Edit:
Below are the screencap of the error from the console:
[image]

Comment: Are those the _only_ errors in your console? Nothing about _"Access-Control"_ headers?

Comment: ya, error in console. How to show Access-Control headers?

Comment: Exactly what is the error message?

Comment: @Phil I added error message. Please see above.

Comment: Is their any errors on the other project (Laravel)?

Comment: @Elie no. there is not.

Comment: Can you post the url in a web browser and see the results?

Comment: Are you using Xampp? This happens to me when my xampp apache and mysql is not yet starting.

Comment: csrf token is used on post requests, I would try what @Phil suggested: setting "Access-Controll" headers for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You could test that by using [CORS Middleware for Laravel 5](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Comment: I don't know what happen, after a few tries it works again.